# HP Laserjet Printer - Google Cloud Print printing multiple pages

Tags: printing, android, printer, network-printer, google-cloud-print

At work we have a HP Laserjet printer. We have it connected up to Google Cloud Print so that everyone around the workplace can connect and print. Recently we have had over 200 pages printed with some HTTP info...

```
GET /privet/info?client_name=android-app HTTP/1.1
Android-Api: 27
X-Privet-Token: ""
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; SM-T580 Build/M1AJQ)
Host: 192.168.2.62:9100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

That is what gets printed all the time. 
It appears to be originating from the tablets we have but I have tried everything that I can think of such as rebooting the tablets, clearing the print cache, altering some settings for the printer but nothing has made a difference.

Has anyone else had an issue like this or have any ideas as to why this is happening? Turning off port 9100 seems to fix the issue but then some of our PC's cannot connect to the printer via WiFi which is needed for certain applications.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The HTTP-like "privet" protocol is part of autodiscovery used by cloud printing - I have no idea why a tablet would send a privet enquiry to the direct-print port 9100 instead of a more typical port number - maybe some misconfiguration of the cloud-printing at the printer?

Comment: @Matt I have a similar problem. Have you found some explanation to your question since ?

Comment: I too have a similar problem it started when trying to set up cloud print on my wife's phone.